# How to put Scrollbar inside a Listbox in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

how can i move the scrollbar inside a listbox? See the photo attached i used a red arrow for explain, here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
window.config(bg='#3c3f41')
window.state('zoomed')
frame_listbox = Frame(window,bg='#3c3f41')
frame_listbox.pack(side=LEFT)
listbox = Listbox(frame_listbox,font=('Helvetica',30))
listbox.pack(padx=400)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
window.mainloop()
```

I tried to put a scrollbar inside a Listbox, i expect to understand if it's possible or not
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to put the scrollbar inside the listbox? It is not a proper way. And there is no photo attached.

Comment: My bad i forgot the photo now if you check i uploaded it, because i prefer inside,is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible but not recommended. It is better to put it just next to the listbox.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, why it's not recommended? Can you explain me how is it possible?

Comment: It may overlap text in the listbox.  To put in inside the listbox, use `scrollbar.place(in_=listbox, relx=1, y=0, relheight=1, anchor="ne")` instead of `scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)`.

Comment: Ok you are right i just tried and the scrollbar overlapped the text in some cases, is there a way to put the scrollbar just outside and closed to the listbox on the right? The way you writed me with 'place' seem very precise, i can use some "x" and "y" coordinate but if i try the program on an other monitor resolution i know that the scrollbar will be in a different position, since "x" and "y" are precise only in the resolution i'm working

Comment: @Forty966996: it's highly unusual to be using such large padding. Rarely should padding be more then 8-10 pixels. What are you trying to accomplish with that? Do you really need 400 pixels of blank space on either side of the listbox?

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to put the scrollbar just to the right of the listbox instead of inside it. To achieve it:

- make the scrollbar child of `frame_listbox` instead of `window`
- move option `padx=400` from `scrollbar.pack(...)` to `frame_listbox.pack(...)`
- pack listbox to the LEFT side

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
window.config(bg='#3c3f41')
window.state('zoomed')
frame_listbox = Frame(window,bg='#3c3f41')
frame_listbox.pack(side=LEFT,padx=400) # added padx=400
listbox = Listbox(frame_listbox,font=('Helvetica',30))
listbox.pack(side=LEFT) # removed padx=400 and added side=LEFT
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame_listbox) # changed parent to frame_listbox
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the help i upvoted your answers, i have done with the pack method and it works, the main problem is when i run the program on an other monitor resolution for example from 1366x768 to 1920x1080 all the widgets are placed in a different position, because the value for padx and pady are perfect only for the resolution i'm working. is there a way that i can be sure that the position i see of the widgets in my screen is the same even on other resolutions? Maybe more big or small  but in a proper scale

Comment: My answer is just based on your code and I don't know where you want the widgets to be put in the window.  You can raise another question and describe your problem and requirement clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this will Help? By using `grid` instead `place`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Listbox Operations")

# create the listbox (note that size is in characters)
listbox1 = tk.Listbox(root, width=50, height=6)
listbox1.grid(row=0, column=0)
 
# create a vertical scrollbar to the right of the listbox
yscroll = tk.Scrollbar(command=listbox1.yview, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
yscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.N+tk.S)
listbox1.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
  
for i in range(1, 50):
    listbox1.insert(tk.END, i)
     
 
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]